# How to resolve an error: getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm getting this error in my coding and not entirely sure how to resolve this.  I've searched to try and resolve this issue but can't seem to find anything that works.  I've done this before but never in a fragment so maybe it could be because of that?

I'm getting following `exception`:

> The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Here is my code:

```
public class TestingFragment extends Fragment {

public TestingFragment(){}
private CheckBox ch;
private Context pref;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testing, container, false);

    ch = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox62);
    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String PREFRENCES_NAME;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(ch.isChecked())
                {
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
            ch.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("cbx62_ischecked" ,true));
            pref.edit().putBoolean("check",false).commit();
            }
        {
        }}
    });
    return rootView;
} }
```

Could anyone please assist me with this?
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change this code :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
```

To :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
```

Remember you cant call `getSharedPreferences` method directly from `Fragment`, because it belongs to the `Activity` class. Hence, you just need to call `getActivity`.

Comment: Thanks! all working now, but it doesn't seem to save the tick in the checbox when exiting the app or returning to this activity?

Comment: @Keithk Great :) Please accept my answer. You need to create a new question for that (its not i dont want to help you, its how SO works - 1 question 1 answer). Just create a new question :)

Comment: @Keithk And let me know the link, i might be able to help you again :)

Comment: Hi Here is the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780499/how-to-save-tick-in-checbox-once-leaving-the-app-or-returing-to-activity)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, was going crazy until your answer made me realize that it needs the activity

Answer (score 3):

The error means that there is no getSharedPreferences method in View class, because getSharedPreferences is a method of Context class. In order to access getSharedPreferences method inside View class you need to provide it with an instance of Context class. Something like:

```
//Instance of Context 
Context pref;

SharedPreferences sharedPref = pref.getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
```

Note: Context pref & String PREFRENCES_NAME should not be null;