# How to save tick in Checkbox once leaving the app or returning to activity?

Tags: android

How can save the tick that is in the checkbox once leaving the app or returing to the activity?

Here is my code:

```
        ch = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox62);
    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String PREFRENCES_NAME;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(ch.isChecked())
                {
            SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
            ch.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("cbx62_ischecked" ,true));
            pref.edit().putBoolean("check",true).commit();

            SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            ch.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("check", true));
            }
        {
        }}
    });
    return rootView;
 }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is my complete code:

```
public class TestingFragment extends Fragment {

public TestingFragment(){}
private CheckBox ch;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_testing, container, false);


    ch = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox62);
    ch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private String PREFRENCES_NAME;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(ch.isChecked())
                {
            SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME,0);
            ch.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("cbx62_ischecked" ,true));
            pref.edit().putBoolean("check",true).commit();               

            }
        {
        }}
    });
    return rootView;
 }
}
```

I have removed the code were i repeated `ch.setChecked(pref.getBoolean("cbx62_ischecked" ,true));`  I have tested again and still doens't seem to work.

Comment: what problem you facing now? And y u defining shared preferences multiple time?

Comment: It doesn't seem to save the tick in the checkbox when i exit the app and returning or when moving to one activty and then back to this activity.

Comment: Why are you calling ch.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("check", true)); 2 times? And please add the code where you insert the shared preferences

Comment: Have posted complete code.

Answer (score 1):

In OnCreate() method define this

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Pref",0);  // better make it global
```

Now when clicking on checkbox

```
ch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(pref.getBoolean("check", false))
                    {
                        ch.setChecked(false);
                        pref.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();

                    } else {
                        ch.setChecked(true);
                        pref.edit().putBoolean("check", true).commit();
                    }
        }
    });
```

And write following code in onResume()

```
       if(pref.getBoolean("check", false))
                    {
                        ch.setChecked(false);

                    } else {
                        ch.setChecked(true);
                    }
```

Comment: just type onresume and press `Ctrl` + `Space`. Its a overriden method